# How can I redirect two actions instead of one action

Tags: grails

here is my controller:

```
def save = {
    def productNameInstance = new ProductName(params)
    if (pharmacyMasterUpdateCompositeService.addProductName(productNameInstance)) {
        flash.message = "${message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'productName.label', default: 'ProductName'), productNameInstance.id])}"
        redirect(action: "show", id: productNameInstance.id)
    }
    else {
        render(view: "create", model: [productNameInstance: productNameInstance])
    }
}
```

where addProductName(productNameInstance) is calling service that is defined in another class.
Here if you see redirecting is happening only at action :"show" if page is created.
My problem is how can i redirect two action like "show" and "print" at the same time where my "print" action downloads a pdf file ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the [chain](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#redirectsAndChaining) method.

```
def save = {
def productNameInstance = new ProductName(params)
if (pharmacyMasterUpdateCompositeService.addProductName(productNameInstance)) {
   //...        
  chain(action: "print", params: [id: roductNameInstance.id])
}
else {
    render(view: "create", model: [productNameInstance: productNameInstance])
}

def print = {
//...
chain(action: "show", params: params)
}

def show  = {  }


}
```